# Анимация как в Gmail Android

Tags: android, transition

В приложении Gmail на андроид используется анимация, аналогичная размещённой по ссылке

https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1DenoCsHNb_H1S1zErzmGCxhz6wjmdO8y%2F01-hierarchy-parentchild.mp4

Я не уверен, что правильно все понимаю, но по моему происходит следующее

1) фейдится начальный экран
2) кликнутое view разрастается в контейнер

я пытаюсь реализовать такое на фрагментах

по клику на view я жду какое то время, чтобы отработала аниация риппла (150 мс)

потом начинаю транзакцию

выбрал слайд, потому что ChangeBounds не дает никакого видимого эффекта

```
@Override
public void goAlarm(View view, int id) {
    Fragment previousFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
    Fragment nextFragment = AlarmFragment.newInstance(id);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    previousFragment.setExitTransition(
            new TransitionSet()
                    .setDuration(DURATION)
                    .setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER)
                    .addTransition(new Fade()));
    nextFragment.setEnterTransition(
            new TransitionSet()
                    .setDuration(150)
                    .addTarget(view.getTransitionName())
                    .addTransition(new Slide())
    );

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, nextFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Разумеется в итоге это выглядит не очень, слайд явно не из этой оперы, но какой из транзишнов выбрать и как сделать так, чтобы shared элемент разрастался в контейнер, который "разворачивается"? В гугле полно красивых примеров, но я почему то не могу это воспроизвести на своём устройстве.

Я так понимаю надо сделать

```
    fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(view, view.getTransitionName());
```

Но либо я что то делаю не так, либо одно из двух. Я сегодня перепробовал уже пожалуй миллион вариантов

добавлял shared element в транзакцию, добавлял target view к фрагменту с которого ухожу и target transition name фрагменту на который прихожу, выбрал разные транзишны, ничего даже близко пожожего не получается. ChangeBound, ChangeClipBounds выглядели у меня - никак, в смысле что визуально я не видел вообще никакого эффекта. Какая правильная последовательность действий для того, чтобы правильно заресайзить айтем в "разворачиваемую" часть следующего фрагмента?

Мой ресайклер

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:transitionGroup="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_item_alarm"
    tools:visibility="gone" />
```

Мой айтем

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:transitionName="container"
    android:background="@drawable/non_transparent_selectable_item_background">  
**...**
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout >
```

мой следующий фрагмент

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_black_54"
    tools:layout_marginTop="24dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/main_sleep_blue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:transitionName="container"
       android:id="@+id/container"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:background="@color/main_white_100"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

       **...**

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Я бы сделал так: берем координаты итема, берем холдер итема, биндим его, получаем копию этой вью, добавляем вью поверх списка и ставим копию на те же координаты. Фейдим список, копию итема анимируем вверх, формируем "экран" с инфой.